# nested foreach statement in java

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

Is it possible to nest foreach statements in java and start the nested statement at the current index that the outer foreach loop is at?

So if I have

```
List<myObj> myObjList = new ArrayList<myObj>();

for (myObj o : myObjList){
    // how do I start the nested for loop at the current spot in the list?
    for(

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should recheck that acceptance. Tim S is doing exactly what you're asking for. And the basic idea can be applied without the use of a sublist by accessing by index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do it by keeping track of the index yourself, then using [`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) to start the inner loop at the right spot:

```
int i = 0;
for (myObj o1 : myObjList) {
    for (myObj o2 : myObjList.subList(i, myObjList.size())) {
        // do something
    }
    i++;
}
```

I think this is clearer than using basic `for` loops, but that's certainly debatable. However, both should work, so the choice is yours. Note that if you are using a collection that does not implement `List<E>`, this will not work (`subList` is defined on `List<E>` as the idea of an "index" really only makes sense for lists).

Answer (score 6):

No. [Enhanced `for` loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) conceal the current index of the loop. You need to use a [basic for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) which uses an index.

Comment: is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use an index based loop rather than an enhanced for loop

Answer (score 1):

While you *could* do something like this, it would be extremely sub-optimal.  Consider that the `indexOf` method would be iterating across the entire list (again!) to find the object.  Note also that it depends on myObjList being an ordered collection (list):

```
List<myObj> myObjList = new ArrayList<myObj>();

for (myObj o : myObjList){
    int idx = myObjList.indexOf(o);
    for(myObj blah : myObjList.subList(idx, myObjList.size()) {
        ...
    }

}
```

far better:

```
int myObjListSize = myObjList.size();
for (int outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < myObjListSize ; outerIndex++){
    for(int innerIndex = outerIndex; innerIndex < myObjListSize ; innerIndex++) {
        myObj o = myObjList.get(innerIndex);
    }

}
```

---

other note: `class myObj` should be capitalized to `class MyObj` to adhere to Java naming standards