# Removing duplicates from list with additional condition

Tags: java, list, loops, iterator

I've faced quite sophisticated task (at least for me). Let's say we have `List<E>`, `E` has two fields `A` and `B`. List might have duplicates. We need to remove instances of `E` which are duplicated by `A` field and leave that one which have the most `B` (let's say we can compare it like some primitive).

Example:
**Input:** `[{1; 1}, {1; 2}, {3; 4}, {3; 3}, {3; 1}, {2; 2}]`
**Output:** `[{1; 2}, {3; 4}, {2; 2}]`
First thing that have come to my mind is just to use nested `for` loop, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802618/nested-foreach-statement-in-java). But first of all I'm not sure that removing nodes of list inside the loop will work fine. And secondly, it would be better to make inner `for` iterate not through whole list, but from outer iterator to the end of list and in this case we might find out that outer iterator is "smaller" then inner one, so we need to remove it, and again i'm not sure if it will harm the loop.
So my question in a nutshell is: are we able to write a reliable code with `for` loops and how would you implement it, or what other design would you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use streams. Let's start with some dummy type definitions:

```
interface E {
    A getA();
    B getB();
}

interface A {}

interface B extends Comparable<B> {}
```

Now let's say you have some `List<E> list`. You can stream and collect elements with maximum `B`, grouping by `A`, and then just grab the values of the map:

```
Collection<E> maxB = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(E::getA,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(E::getB)),
                        Optional::get)))
        .values();
```

Comment: Wow! After 6 months of java I still don't use streams. Definitely gonna go deep in it since it provide so wide functionality.

Comment: @Russiancold Yup, streams are great! There definitely is a learning curve, but you won't regret the investment.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that i learned today about lists, is to iterate through the list backwards if you want to remove an item. This way you avoid indexoutofrange exceptions. 
Otherwise i would do it with for loops, don't have a better idea atm.

Comment: Can you provide some implementation? It's not obvious for me how would I iterate backward with nested for. Should I create custom Iterator for this?